# OptaPlanner - SolverState in daemonMode

Tags: java, optaplanner

Is there a way to get the state of a `Solver` which is in daemon mode but currently waiting?
Because `Solver.isSolving()` always returns `true` even though the `Thread` is currently waiting.

Comment: Currently there isn't a way, but it sounds like a reasonable feature request. Please create a jira. What's the use case / motivation? Why would you care?

Comment: Presuming there's a good use case, the fix itself should be straightforward in [this class](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-core/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/core/impl/solver/BasicPlumbingTermination.java)